# Toggle option in mplayer input.conf?

Tags: configuration, input, mplayer

I've learnt `af_del scaletempo` syntax from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/lZ1omXZaACg).

So, i put this 2 lines in my ~/.mplayer/input.conf:

```
; af_add scaletempo
' af_del scaletempo
```

This work fine, but i'm looking for **toggle** option to try to not waste 2 shortcut keys in only one functionality. I tried `af_clr` but no luck.

I try to read `info/man mplayer` but i can't found any keyword mentioned about `_del` and `_add`, so i really curious how that person know such syntax. I might able to figure out `toggle` syntax by myself if i know where the docs is.

Please note that you should test with `-speed 1.21` option to make scaletempo applicable.

What's the **toggle** syntax in input.conf of mplayer ?

**[UPDATE]**

I found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161030172336/http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2010-June.txt):

```
af_add <filter_arguments_list>  (comma separated list of audio filters
with parameters)
    (experimental) Load the given list of audio filters.

af_clr
    (experimental) Unload all loaded audio filters.

af_del <filter_name_list> (comma separated list of audio filter's names)
    (experimental) Unload the first occurrence of the filters, if loaded.

af_switch <filter_arguments_list> (comma separated list of audio filters
with parameters)
    (experimental) Remove all the audio filters and replace them with the
given list.
```

And [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161030172316/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpv-player/mpv/master/DOCS/mplayer-changes.rst):

| `af_switch`, `af_add`, ... | `af set|add|...`                     |

But `' af_switch scaletempo` not working to toggle though, any idea ?

Comment: Use `mpv` instead of `mplayer`. It's an mplayer fork, but with more features. In `mpv` you can bind a key to run any script, then you can write your own mini shellscript for toggling.

Comment: @IporSircer Is it possible to do `apt-get install mpv` with libcaca enabled without manually compile ? I read about `brew install --with-libcaca` but i'm not using `brew`. I want to play it in Virtual Console with `-vo caca -quite` when X is not an option.

Comment: Yes, it already includes libcaca in Debian. Very similar configuration schema to mplayer, but some variables has been renamed.

Comment: @IporSircer I'm using Kali, unfortunately `mpv --vo=help` doesn't shows caca. One thing i really like about `mpv` is i can move the borderless window which `mplayer` can't do.